# jQuery "load()" Can't Load PHP "curl_exec()" Result

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want an HTML file to load the result of "curl_exec()" method of a PHP file.

The PHP file is located in localhost, and the HTML file can be anywhere.

Eg the PHP file name is "curl.php".

I used jQuery "load()" to load the result, but it doesn't work, even after I upload the files to a web server.

The HTML file code:

http://jsfiddle.net/aTkEZ/

The "curl.php" code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Quk8N/

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried some basic debugging - what does the browser show for the `load()` request ? any response ? what does the `curl_exec()` return ?

Comment: When I open the HTML file in the browser, it shows me nothing. If I open "http://localhost/curl.php" directly in the browser, it shows the web page I requested.

Comment: Is the HTML file also hosted on your server?

Comment: Both HTML and PHP file are stored in my hard disk. The PHP file is in localhost folder. But I've tried to upload them to a web server, also doesn't work.

Comment: Well your code works for me when both are running on the same server. You need to check the JavaScript console in your browser to see what's failing.

Comment: OK, this is the message from Chrome: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/curl.php. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. ?

Comment: Are you *sure* you're running the HTML through your webserver? That's the error I get when I run it locally.

Comment: Try a relative path, eg, "/curl.php", to ensure the browser doesn't impose its same-origin policy.

Comment: Yes I need to store the file locally. I tried again with online, this is the message: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php".
error404.000webhost.com:2Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
curl.html:12Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. What does it mean? I've tried the relative path (/curl.php), also doesn't work.

Comment: jQuery is not defined, did you place the jQuery code inside document.ready, and did you add jQuery ?

Comment: I've uploaded the jQuery. Now the message is: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php".
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null. But I need the files to work in localhost.

Comment: Now your trying to use jQuery's append, html or similar on an object that does not exists.

Comment: You are trying this on a LAMP installation locally, where you have a webserver, PHP etc. ???

Comment: When I tried this locally (WAMP installation), the console message is: XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost/curl.php. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.   When I tried this online (uploaded into an online web server), the console message is: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "analytics.hosting24.com/count.php";. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null

Comment: Ok, locally you have something wrong with the adress for curl.php, try using 127.0.0.1 or whatever you use as IP locally. On the webserver you are now trying to use appendChild on an object that is'nt there. appendChild is used by jQuery in all appending functions, like .html() etc. so you are probably trying to append to an object that does not exist, either you have a typo, the DOM is not ready and the element does not exist, or something else is wrong. Try using $.ajax and log the returned data to the console to see what is returned from the ajax call.

Comment: I've used the code in your answer, and added error callback to see the error message in console. When testing locally, the error message is: http://jsfiddle.net/L7QFd/. When testing on the web server (online), the error message is: http://jsfiddle.net/mFqRF/

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should probably set some parameters for that cURL call, something like this:

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "http://antithesiscomedy.com/");
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  $html = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $html;
?>
```

Even adding a header and useragent should be considered depending on the site your trying to get the source from.

Test the cURL by opening the file in your browser and see if it returns the page, then continue and see if you can fetch it with Ajax.

Try replacing that load function with $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/curl.php",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "html",
   success: function(data) {
      $(document).html(data);
   }
});
```

and see if that works?

Answer (score 1):

AJAX requests through javascript are most often bound to a same-origin policy. This means that unless the browser thinks that the page being fetched is on the same server as the page currently being executed, it will return an error.

To see if an error is returned, you should add a callback like this:

```
$('#content').load(url, function (data, error) {
    // check the error parameter to see if there was an
    // error and react accordingly
});
```

There can be some issues with same origin policy with localhost, or at least I have had some issues with same origin policy with localhost. Try uploading the files to an actual host somewhere.

Comment: Tested locally, it only returns "error" as the message. Then I reuploaded it to an online web server, the message is: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php".
error404.000webhost.com:2Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
curl.html:12Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. What does it mean?

Comment: That means that there are errors in the file you are trying to fetch, I think. Without seeing the code you are actually using I can only speculate (it says there is an error on line 12, and whilst the line numbers PHP generates can be off I've not seen it that off before).